# Multiple choice question for dominant strategy in table

Tags: probability, combinatorics

```
             Frank: Play         Frank: Stay              
John: Play    J=5;F=10            J=4;F=12
John: Stay    J=1;F=6             J=14;F=7

A. John's dominant strategy is play.
B. John's dominant strategy is stay.
C. Frank's dominant strategy is play.
D. Frank's dominant strategy is stay.
```

The answer key says the answer is D., but I don't see why it also can't be A. Is there an easy way to spot the answer to these kinds of question?

Answer (score 2):

If Frank stays (D):

- if John plays, Frank's payoff is 12 > 10
- if John stays, Frank's payoff is 7 > 6

In both cases (whatever John does), Frank's payoff is greater if he stays than if he plays. Thus Frank's dominant strategy is to stay.

Now, for (A), John does *not* actually have any dominant strategy: if he plays, then it's better if Frank plays but worse if Frank stays (as $5>1$ but $4 < 14$). Conversely, if John stays then its worse if Frank plays (payoff of $1$ instead of the $5$ had he chosen to stay).